# Trivial solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

For the ODE (with positive constant coefficients $A,B,C$)
$$
\frac{d^4}{dx^4}y-A\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y+B\frac{d}{dx}y-Cy=0,\quad 0<x<1
$$
together with boundary conditions
$$
y(0)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y(0)=0,\quad y(1)=\frac{d}{dx}y(1)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y(1)=\frac{d^3}{dx^3}y(1)=0
$$
is there only the trivial zero solution? If the answer is yes, how can we prove it? A more involved version of the question concerns the boundary conditions
$$
y(0)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y(0)=0,\quad y(1)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y(1)=0,\quad \frac{d^3}{dx^3}y(1)=A\frac{d}{dx}y(1)
$$
Is there only the trivial zero solution in this case also? Many thanks.

Comment: For a 4th degree ODE you only get 4 slots for boundary conditions. With 5 conditions the problem in general will have no solution.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. But one idea is to take a solution satisfying four of the boundary conditions, apply the remaing boundary condition(s) to that solution, and then conclude that this solution can then only be the zero solution.

Comment: The first question has a complete set of initial conditions at $x=1$, so the only solution is trivial.  The second one, fix B and C.  There might be a sequence of eigenvalues $A_n=A_n(B,C)$ where a nontrivial solution obeys the first four conditions.  Then calculate $D_n(B,C)=y'''(1)/y'(1)$.  The surfaces $z=A_n(B,C)$ and $z=D_n(B,C)$ may intersect.

Comment: @Empy2: Thanks. I got it for the first one, which is a consequence of the uniqueness theorem. For the second one, however, I am not sure. We can show that a nontrivial solution satisfying the first four boundary conditions exists. That is understood. But I can't fiugre out how to use the remaining boundary condition to show that the solution is in fact the trivial one.

Comment: Multiply by the right function of $y$, then integrate.